# How to add Jasper Report to JDeveloper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jdeveloper

I made a report using iReport tool.but i don't know how to add that report to project in JDeveloper.If possible tell me how to add variable from class to Report.

Comment: What do you mean `how to add variable from class to Report`? Are you talking about JasperReports API?

Comment: No i just want to pass values to .xml file generated by iReport tool.

Comment: You should use JasperReports API to pass variable (parameters, etc.) to the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for adding a variable to jasper report you need to add parameter to jasper report.These option you can find on Menubar.And in Java you can add parameter method to pass the value of your variables.addProperty(variable_name,value).